# Função contar caracteres JavaScript + PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho essa função que conta os caracteres e me mostra o valor:

```
function calcular(el) {
  var valor = document.getElementById('valor');
  var precoPorLetra = 10;
  var espacos = (el.value.split(" ").length - 1); //conta espacos
  var caracteres = el.value.length;
  valor.value = parseFloat( (caracteres - espacos) * precoPorLetra).toFixed(2); //formatado para duas casas decimais
}
```

Preciso pegar o "precoPorLetra" do banco de dados (PHP + MYSQL).
Preciso mostrar o "valor" também em um `<span>`

```
<span id="valor"></span>
```

Mas não aparece nada

```
Nome: <input onkeyup="calcular(this)" type="text" />
Valor: <input id="valor" type="text" readonly />
```

Comment: Se quer pegar o valor de preço por letra do mysql, terá que fazer uma requisição ajax.

Comment: somente via ajax? E como eu faria isso?

Comment: Da pra fazer tanto por ajax, quanto pegar o valor da váriavel PHP no JS. Exemplo de requisição ajax: http://vinteum.com/ajax-facil-com-jquery/ ou passe a variável do php para o JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/415888/7168666

Comment: A segunda opção deu certinha... mas agora como eu faço para exibir alem do input em um span tbm

Comment: Adicione o código do `span` na pergunta e caso exista algo no JS que faz referência ao `span`, coloque-o também. Mas pra dar um norte para você, cria um `span` e coloca um id nele, e mantar printar o valor da variável `precoPorLetra`, nesse span, através do ID.

Comment: Veja se assim ajuda

Comment: Não pode haver dois IDs iguais. Altere o ID do SPAN para "valor_total" e adicione na função a linha `document.getElementById('valor_total').innerHTML = "R$"+preco_final;`. E altere `valor.value` para `preco_final`.

Comment: Preço por letra? ponto, dois pontos, interrogação, traço, parenteses  etccc conta como letra?

Comment: Acho q a resposta do leo foi mais que completa, valide-a como correta.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo sim Léo... contam tbm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Com Javascript** para exibir em um span também basta inserir essa linha

```
document.getElementById('valor_span').innerHTML = "R$ "+preco_total;
```

mudando o valor do `id` na tag `span` para `valor_span` pois `id=valor` já foi atribuído ao `input`

```js
function calcular(el) {
  var valor = document.getElementById('valor');
  var precoPorLetra = 10;
  var espacos = (el.value.split(" ").length - 1); //quantidade de espacos
  var caracteres = el.value.length;
  preco_total = valor.value = parseFloat( (caracteres - espacos) * precoPorLetra).toFixed(2); //duas casas decimais
  
  document.getElementById('valor_span').innerHTML = "R$ "+preco_total;
  
}
```

```html
Nome: <input onkeyup="calcular(this)" type="text" />
Valor: <input id="valor" type="text" readonly />

<span id="valor_span"></span>
```

**Com jquery**

- Aceita somente letras, inclusive acentuadas (para não inflacionar os preços com virgulas, pontos, caracteres especias e etc :D )
- Separador de milhar `.` (ponto) e decimal `,` (virgula)
- Espaços são aceitos porém não são contabilizados

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.soLetras').keyup(function (el) {
    var precoPorLetra = 10;

      $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú ]/g,''));
      var nome = document.getElementById('nome');
  
      var espacos = (nome.value.split(" ").length - 1);

      var letras = nome.value.length;      
      var total = parseFloat((letras-espacos) * precoPorLetra).toFixed(2);
     
      total=total.replace(".", ",");
      
      total=total.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
     
      $('.valor').html("R$ " + total); 
      
      valor.value = total;

     
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Nome: <input type="text" class="soLetras" name="nome" id="nome">
Valor: <input id="valor" type="text" readonly />
<span class="valor"></span>
```

> Para aceitar também números substitua essa linha

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú ]/g,''));
```

por essa linha

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9 ]/g,''));
```

### PHP

O valor de `precoPorLetra` vindo do banco pode ser atribuído no script da seguinte forma:

```
var precoPorLetra = <?php echo $nomeVariavel ?>;
```

Comment: Obrigado... funcionou certinho

Comment: Como faço agora para pegar a quantidade de caracteres digitados, sem os espaços :D

Comment: `function contacaracteres(){ var nome_manuscrito = document.nome_manuscrito.value; nome_manuscrito = nome_manuscrito.replace(/ /g,''); document.getElementById('caracteres').value = nome_manuscrito.length;}` mas não deu certo o input e o span

Comment: @BetinhoSilva, no jquery  var letrasSemEspacos= (letras-espacos);

Comment: Np javascript  var letrasSemEspacos=(caracteres - espacos);